# How make text follow image resize

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm having trouble making a layout that was asked me.

I have this image that needs resize, and I need to make the texts that are on top of it follow the image resize.

For example:

There is a word that is in the left of the face of a women, when I resize the window the image changes, but the text is still static.. in the same place.

To illustrate my problem I created a codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MwoJNb?editors=110

In the first 'hero', the picture has a text and a line and when you resize, you can see that the text follows the line.

In the second 'hero', the image only has the line and the text is HTML, when you resize the line moves, but the text stay in the same place

I want make the same behavior happened in the second, but using text, possible?

thanks! :)

```
<div class="hero"></div>
<div class="hero2">
  <h1 class="hero2__text">Text<h1>
</div>

* {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
.hero {
  background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/2ZxJ9UY.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: top center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  display: block;
}
.hero {
  background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/2ZxJ9UY.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: top center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  display: block;
}
.hero2 {
  margin-top: 50px;
  background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/aD6yIXf.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: top center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  display: block;
}
.hero2__text {
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  top: 120px;
  left: 160px;
}
```

Comment: You can try listening for window.resize event and get the current width/height of document then adjust your text size/layout accordingly.

Comment: Is your codepen example literally what you want a line next to your text? I ask because if so then setting a border on your h1 you could accomplish this and then use @media queries on your css to resize accordingly. Otherwise you might need something like http://fittextjs.com/

Comment: nop @LeoBauza, is just an example, i have a complex image (i can't show because is industry secret)..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think something like this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1xqbk25v/ in combination with http://fittextjs.com/ might work out for you.

The relevant code for aligning the text vertically with the image is this:

```
.hero2 {
    position: relative;
}
.hero2__text {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    margin: 0px;
}
.img {
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-left: 100px;
}
```